# Error in Oracle query

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

```
LEFT JOIN c_invoiceline cl ON CASE WHEN ml.m_inoutline_id>0 
THEN  cl.c_orderline_id=ol.c_orderline_id AND cl.m_inoutline_id=ml.m_inoutline_id
    ELSE cl.c_orderline_id=ol.c_orderline_id
    END
```

This query is working fine in postgres and in oracle it is showing error.The error message is "ora-00905:Missing keyword"

Comment: Please learn to format your posts after almost 30 ones.

Comment: Add the errormessage please.

Comment: The query shows an error because it is not a valid query. No, just joking; post the complete query here, not just the join clause, so we can help you.

Comment: ... and even the join clause itself is, apparently, not valid.

Comment: It is working fine in postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was surprised that this works in PostgreSQL, but it does.

This should work with any RDBMS:

```
LEFT JOIN c_invoiceline cl
  ON (      ( cl.c_orderline_id=ol.c_orderline_id )
        AND (    ml.m_inoutline_id > 0 AND cl.m_inoutline_id=ml.m_inoutline_id
              OR ml.m_inoutline_id <= 0
            )
     )
```

Comment: The logic is different for the above query.

Comment: You are right, the result would have been different for `cl.m_inoutline_id<=0`. Fixed.